# Unable to access variable from innerclass : Kotlin android

Tags: android, class, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin development in android. here I am trying to access a variable defined in a class from it's inner class as below.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var frags: MutableList<Fragment> = mutableListOf()

//.............onCreate and other methods ....

    internal class CustAdapter(var arrayList: ArrayList<NavigationData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder!!.bindItems(arrayList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.navigation_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindItems(data: NavigationData) {


            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                   frags.add(BoardFrag()) ///// here i'm getting error "unresolved symbol"

            }
        }
    }
}    
}
```

inside inner class `MyViewHolder` it is not allowing me to access any variable of outer scope.

even I'm unable to access view ids imported from 
`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` inside inner class methods.

I was able to access variables in such a way in `java` but i have read many question on stackoverflow but i didn't get answer yet.

Comment: Use inner, not internal =)

Comment: Use  ***inner*** keyword instead of internal                                   
 `class parent {                   
                        val m=1;   
         inner class child{                                                         
                                        print(m)}                                                        
                                                }`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You should use the inner modifier in your adapter.

This modifier makes the inner class have access to the members of the outer class

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This tiny mistake was bitting me  from two days and you saved my another day

Comment: You are welcome! The name internal and inner is really tricky... Keep with protected would be better I guess

Comment: I do not know the difference between protected and internal and inner but i will try to sort it out on my own

Answer (score 50):

Define your nested class as `inner` then you will be able to access an outer class's member variable.

```
class OuterClass{

var accessMe ="access me from Inner Class"

    inner class InnerClass{

       //....

   
        fun accessingOuterClassVariable(){

           accessMe = "Now the variable is accessed"

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the call-site for `var accessMe`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Please check , I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 9):

to answer this question for the fast an easy way i would do something like following :

```
class OuterClass{

private var accessibleInside: CustomObject? = null
inner class InnerClass{

    //....
}
```

now the `CustomObject` could be anything from `Context` to `String` hope this helps someone.